# Computing an integral explicitly

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I have the following integral: let $k$ be a positive fixed integer and $\varepsilon \in (0,1/k)$. Let $t>0$ and $r>0$. We consider
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{t/2} (t^{2\varepsilon} - s^{2\varepsilon})^{-k/2} s^r ds dt.$$

I know this integral converges, e.g. observe that $t^{-k\varepsilon}<(t^{2\varepsilon} - s^{2\varepsilon})^{-k/2}<(1-2^{-2\varepsilon})^{-k/2}t^{-k\varepsilon}$. Then one easily integrates and gets a finite value. Also, it is intuitive since the only singularity is when $s\sim t$ which is not on the domain of integration and when $s\sim 0$ there is no singularity since $r>0$.

My question is: how can I compute this integral explicitly? or at least find a better bound of it? I tried to use the Beta function but I failed... Any suggestion is very welcome!
Thanks :)